# Create slideshow-like movie from photos

Tags: windows, video, photography, slideshow

I really like the new iOS-feature that automatically creates slideshow-like movies from photo albums. As far as I know, something similar is also available in iPhoto on Macs, but I'm looking for something comparable for Windows.

I especially like the following features:

- it automatically selects which photos to include (and does that quite intelligently, omitting almost similar picture, etc.),
- it automatically puts them in a nice order (which is not necessarily by time),
- it adds some pan & zoom animations and aligns transitions with music,
- it shows multiple photos at a time, creating a short video even for a lot of photos,
- and everything happens completely automatically.

Is there anything similar for Windows?

What I found so far is all quite old, e.g. using Movie Maker, and requires you to do a lot of the steps manually.